# Outlook web add-in along with mail body

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to create web add-in for outlook 365. Add-in button should display above the mail body. As of my understanding contextual add-in is only way to achieve this. So how to create this add-in any sample available for this?(I'm not able to achieve this with Microsoft outlook dev [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins) )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problem in finding out this info. There are several ways to display the icon.

You do this by setting `type` in `ExtensionPoint` of Manifest file. Available options are [listed here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/extensionpoint#extension-points-for-outlook-add-in-commands).

The one you are probably looking for is: `<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">`

You can also see the [available icon here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook).